# How to link (import) libs with dlls

Tags: python, windows, bazel

With the following rules:

```
# in @org_python
cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = [
         "libs/python35.lib",
    ],
    ...

# in //
cc_binary(
    name = "bin",
    srcs = [
        "mypybinding.cpp",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@org_python//:lib",
    ],
```

linking emits a lot of:

```
mypybinding.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyType_Type
```

Which steps are necessary to link import libraries properly?

---

Seems like part of the problem is this entry in `python35.lib`:

```
Version      : 0
Machine      : 8664 (x64)
TimeDateStamp: 576F0350 Sun Jun 26 00:18:56 2016
SizeOfData   : 00000019
DLL name     : python35.dll
Symbol name  : PyType_Type
Type         : data
Name type    : name
Hint         : 794
Name         : PyType_Type
```

I assume this means that the symbol is only available in the DLL and fully static linking not possible.

I tried putting the dlls into `srcs` but it seems like these are only passed directly to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `srcs`, use `linkopts` instead:

```
cc_library(
    ...
    linkopts = ["-Wl,python35.lib"],
)
```

See [this example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/3e87c626ed76536420aa06e4c258209b32bb76e0/src/main/cpp/BUILD#L60).

Comment: I think that does not apply for 3 reasons: 1. `python35.lib` is not in system but a source file 2. `python35.lib` is a import lib only (not sure for the example libs) and 3. in order to add something like `-Wl,$(location libs/python35.lib)` to `linkopts` I would need to specify the file as a dependency, which I do not know how.

Comment: Added some more details to the question.

Comment: The workaround for 0.4.4 (courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/users/8053222/yun-peng): `linkopts = ["-Lexternal/org_python/libs/", "-Wl,python35.lib"]` does not seem to work for 0.5.1 anymore.

Comment: Hmm, I think your original rules should work. Where does your BAZEL_PYTHON point to? Because, in [cc_configure.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl#L763), we are adding it's `include` and `libs` path to `INCLUDE` and `LIB` environment variable. Is it the same python as `libs/python35.lib` belongs to? Can you share your example project with me so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: So I made `BAZEL_PYTHON` point now to  the same installation as `libs/python35.lib` and it still does not work. Am trying to produce a minimal test case.